# How to increase box-shadow by clicking on img?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my code set up so that when the user clicks on the img, the box-shadow will increase. However, my code only increases the box-shadow once, and I don't really understand why. I guess it has something to do with .on(), but I'm not really sure why this happening. If anyone could provide some insight, I would be very appreciative.

```
  var hshadow=10;
  var vshadow=10;
  function boostShadow() {
      hshadow= hshadow + 5;
      vshadow= vshadow + 5;
      hshadow=hshadow.toString() + "px ";
      vshadow=vshadow.toString() + "px ";
      $("img").css("box-shadow",hshadow + vshadow +"5px #565656");
  }

  $("img").on("click",function () {
      boostShadow();
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you set the variables to strings when you add `"px"` to them and that prevents further addition to them in the next click. Try this below:

```
var hshadow = 10,
    vshadow = 10;
function boostShadow(image) {
    hshadow += 5;
    vshadow += 5;
    $(image).css("box-shadow",hshadow+"px " + vshadow+"px 5px #565656");
}

$("img").on("click",function () {
    // We pass the clicked image as a variable so only
    // that image's box-shadow is altered
    boostShadow(this);
});
```

Comment: Ah ok, can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: I always am fascinated at how passing `this` from one function to another just links them together.  Still do not get it, but it works and I'm just happy that it works that way.